# How to execute `zsh -c "echo -n $ZSH_CUSTOM"` in Rust

Tags: shell, process, zsh

I am trying to execute the following zsh command in Rust using
[`Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html):

```bash
$ zsh -c "echo -n $ZSH_CUSTOM"
/home/steve/.oh-my-zsh/custom%
```

```rust
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let mut zsh = Command::new("zsh");
    zsh.args(["-c", "echo -n $ZSH_CUSTOM"]);
    let output = zsh.output().unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", output);
}
```

However, for the above Rust code, I am getting an unexpected result:

```bash
$ cargo r -q
Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(0)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }
```

Anyway to make the Rust code have the same output with that `zsh` command? Thanks in advance!

BTW, my environment:

```bash
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.9 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

$ uname -a
Linux localhost 6.3.4-101.fc37.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat May 27 15:09:40 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ rustc --version
rustc 1.69.0 (84c898d65 2023-04-16)
```

If it matters.

Comment: First question is: what happens if you try to run `zsh.args (["-c", "echo foo"])`? Do you see the `foo` in the output in that case?

Comment: Second question is: what happens if you run `zsh -c 'echo $ZSH_CUSTOM'` in your terminal (note the single quotes instead of the double quotes)? This is  closer to what your Rust code does…

Comment: Also what happens if you do `println!("{:?}", std::env::var ("ZSH_CUSTOM"));` in Rust?

Comment: @Jmb For your first question, output is: `Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(0)), stdout: "foo\n", stderr: "" }`, I can see `foo` in the output. For the second question, nothing is printed, and `$?` gives 0, I guess this is equivalent to my rust code

Comment: `println!("{:?}", std::env::var ("ZSH_CUSTOM"));` gives `Err(NotPresent)`

Comment: And if you try without `cargo`. I.e. run `./target/debug/my_crate` (replace `my_crate` with the name of your crate)?

Comment: @Jmb I have the same doubt, the rust process is a child process of my zsh shell, why doesn't it have `ZSH_CUSTOM` set. `./target/debug/my_crate` gives the same result as `cargo r -q`, `Err(NotPresent)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `ZSH_CUSTOM` variable is not exported by your shell. Try to do `export ZSH_CUSTOM` before running your program.

What happens is that when you run `zsh -c "echo -n $ZSH_CUSTOM"` in an interactive shell, the `ZSH_CUSTOM` variable is expanded *by the interactive shell,* which then calls `zsh -c "echo -n /home/steve/.oh-my-zsh/custom"`. When you call it from Rust (or if you call `zsh -c 'echo -n $ZSH_CUSTOM'` with single quotes), then the *called* shell attempts to expand `ZSH_CUSTOM`, but since it's not exported the expansion is an empty string.

Comment: Yes, `zsh` does not export it, that is the root cause, thanks for debugging with me! Thx!